# Bootstrap 5 grid - hide elements on small

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have the following, which look perfect the way i want on large screen, but when switched to mobile (using dev tools), it seems the columns stack on each other instead of horizontal

Basically on small screen, i want to hide the first and second last column, and re-size the columns as blow, but they stack.

I haven tried the codepen online but that seems to even mess it up more (copied examples from bootsrap, pasted it in and they stack on codepens but they dont on bootsrap website), anyways here is my code that I am trying to arrange diff on screen sizes

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1 d-none d-sm-block">date</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-2">logo</div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-9">title</div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 d-none d-sm-block">cat</div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1">menu</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `d-sm-block` will **show** the elements on SM breakpoint. What exaclty is unclear about it? Did you check the official documentation about [display](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/display/) and [breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/breakpoints/)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my expertise with Bootstrap, I used the following to hide elements **.d-*-none**. You can try using **.d-sm-none .d-md-block**